# Magento Form with Tabs Fieldset Issue

Tags: magento

I'm writing a custom Magento module for my store and I'm facing a weird issue with a fieldset in one form. The form is assigned to a tab, however the fieldset starts from the top of container, not from just below buttons area. Please see the image attached
[image: Problematic fieldset]

I want it to display like:
[image: Desired Fieldset]

This module is being developed on Magento 1.9.0.1 without any modification whatsoever, just the demo data.

Below is the code for all the classes:
Controller:
added form container and tabs to left column

```
class Koala_Socialmanager_Adminhtml_TwitterController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
public function directTweetAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('koala_socialmanager/twitter_directTweet_tweet','directTweet'))
        ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('koala_socialmanager/twitter_directTweet_edit_tabs'));
    $this->renderLayout();
```

Form container:

```
class Koala_Socialmanager_Block_Twitter_DirectTweet_Tweet extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_blockGroup = 'koala_socialmanager';
    $this->_controller = 'twitter_directTweet';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__('Direct Tweets');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Tweet Now!'));
}
```

}

Tabs:

```
class Koala_Socialmanager_Block_Twitter_DirectTweet_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('tweetTabs');
    $this->setDestinationElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__('Twitter'));
}
public function _beforeToHtml(){
    $this->addTab('form_section_form',array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("Tweet"),
        'title' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("Tweet"),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('koala_socialmanager/twitter_directTweet_edit_tabs_form')->initForm()->toHtml(),
        'active'  => true
    ));

    $this->addTab('form_section_external_media',array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("External Media"),
        'title' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("External Media"),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('koala_socialmanager/twitter_directTweet_edit_tabs_externalMedia')->initForm()->toHtml()
    ));
    $this->addTab('form_section_magento_media',array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("Magento Product Media"),
        'title' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__("Magento Product Media"),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('koala_socialmanager/twitter_directTweet_edit_tabs_magentoProductMedia')->toHtml()
    ));
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

}

And form with fieldset:

```
class Koala_Socialmanager_Block_Twitter_DirectTweet_Edit_Tabs_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function initForm(){
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('socialmanager');


    $helper = Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->__('Tweeter Message')
    ));
    $fieldset->addField('statusUpdate', 'textarea', array(
        'name'=>'tweet',
        'label'=>$helper->__("Tweet this Message:"),
        'after_element_html'=>'<div class="characterCounter">0</div>'
    ));
    Mage::helper('koala_socialmanager')->getTwitterFormScript();
    return $this;
```

I believe I'm missing something silly. Any help appreciated.

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, still don't know the cause though. I simply rewritten everything to another folder changing the class names, created another action in controller called testAction, so all files from DirectTweet folder are located in Message folder, and guess what? when you display that form from testActoin it works as it should, when I display the old form from DirectTweet folder - fieldset is broken.

I have magento cache disabled all the time, I cleared all tmp, cache, session folders, cleared browser cache and had no luck with fixing it, so I'm wondering why the new "version" works even though there is no changes to the code apart from cosmetic ones (removing empty lines, or changed text for labels/headers).

For the last 20 minutes I was comparing file by file in phpstorm, and seriously no differences apart from class names and texts to output.... I'm to tired to think about it anymore.

Below desired output :)

Happy New Year
Paul

[image]